How to push an enemy back by pushing another enemy into them, in Godot 4
So, in the game I am making I added knockback for when the player hits the enemy, but when the enemy is being knocked back, when they run into another enemy, I want that enemy to knocked back as well.
I tried writing the same knockback code for when the enemy collides with the other enemy but it's not working properly.
Here is the code:
func _on_hurt_box_body_entered(body):
if body.is_in_group("Enemy") and is_knocked_back == true:
var damage = Damage.new()
damage.knockback_force = 25.0
body.knockback_vector2 = (global_position - body.global_position).normalized() * damage.knockback_force
body.is_knocked_back = true
body.enemyhealth - 5
enemyhealth - 5
print("knockback")
$knockedtimer.start()


It's not really clear what you're trying to say and who's knocking back who, I would suggest framing the question better and adding an example. From what I can tell maybe you need to use collision_layers & collision_masks to separate the player and enemies maybe this and this will help

Also I don't think enemyhealth - 5 does anything, maybe you meant enemyhealth -= 5 ? But I feel you're taking a unnecessarily complex approach on something that should be rather simple
